# Rails: Conditionally loading associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, associations

I have models `club` and `course` where a course belongs to a club and and a club has many courses.

When I load a club, I also want to load it's associated courses, but I only want to load those that meet a conditional test (`approved? == true`).

It is straightforward how to do this if I were working directly with the courses:

```
@courses = Course.find( :all, :conditions => {:approved => true } )
```

But I would like to do this as part of the statement:

```
@club = Club.find(params[:id])
```

because my views are built that way and I would rather not have to change all of them.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ultimate solution came from a combination of answers, but neither quite got all the way.

**Current solution:**
I utilize a couple of named scopes in the `course` model to achieve the functionality I wanted while keeping my views as universal as possible (being able to dry up code is a must).

So the `course` model looks a bit like this:

```
class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :club

  named_scope :have_approval, :conditions => { :approved => true }
  named_scope :need_approval, :conditions => { :approved => false }
end
```

And to gather all approved courses it is as easy as:

```
@approved_courses = Course.have_approval
```

Or when working with a `club`, getting the approved courses in a club is as easy as:

```
@club = Club.find(:first)
@approved_courses_in_club = @club.courses.have_approval
```

Named scope is the man!

Comment: you can use dynamic scope instead of named_scope i.e.  `@club.courses.scoped_by_approval(true)` OR `@club.courses.scoped_by_approval(false)`.

Answer (score 2):

If you only consider a club's course if it has been approved, you can do

```
class Club < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :courses, :conditions => {:approved => true}
end
```

and in your controller

```
@club = Club.find(params[:id], :include => :courses)
```

Now, I don't know if I misunderstood you, but you said "your views are built that way". Do you mean your controllers? Because if you have such logic in your views... **DHH kills a kitten every time someone does that.**

Comment: Poor kittens, but no. I was afraid of having to load both an `@club` AND `@courses` variable...which would mean getting rid of all of the `@club.courses` references in my views.

I have an admin namespace where I would like to load the unapproved courses (as if the condition wasn't in the model), how would I do that using your solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `default_scope` for this:

```
class Club < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :courses, conditions => {:approved => true}
  default_scope :include => :courses
end

class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
  default_scope :conditions => {:approved => true}
end
```

Now you can do this:

```
@club = Club.find(1) # this will eager load approved courses.
```

**Reference:**

[Article](http://ryandaigle.com/articles/2008/11/18/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-default-scoping) about `default_scope`.

**Note 1**

I changed the `courses` assocation in `Club` class to select approved courses. In theory, this is not required as the `Course` class has a default scope. But, it looks like default scope is not applied for eager loaded queries.

**Note 2**

I personally would not eager load the `Course` objects through `default_scope`. Doing it through a default_scope gives you an unobtrusive solution as desired by you.

I would add the `include` clause to the `find` call to eager load the `Course` objects only when it's required.

**Note 3**

@Ryan Bigg:

Ryan Bates talks about default scopes half way through this his [screen cast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/152-rails-2-3-extras). He gives an example of using the default scopes to exclude deleted records, i.e.

```
default_scope :conditions => "delete_at IS NULL"
```

I consider this use case to be similar. As I perceive the problem, primary operations on the Course model is on approved records and `default_scope` with the `conditions` option ensures that. To override the default_scope, user can use the `with_exclusive_scope` method.

```
Club.with_exclusive_scope{find(1)}
```

Comment: I wouldn't use :conditions **ever** in a `default_scope`: How does Rails differentiate between your `default_scope` conditions and the other group of conditions you specify? I would instead use a `named_scope` for this and call that instead. @Chubas' solution's good too.

Comment: I disagree, filtering `deleted`, and `approved` records is a suitable usage for default_scope. In this case every `find` operation on the `Course` model requires filtering of unapproved courses. In cases where user needs to include the unapproved records, he can use `with_exclusive_scope`.

Comment: The user says: `because my views are built that way and I would rather not have to change all of them.`, this solution enables the user to achieve the functionality un-obtrusively.

Comment: I have updated my answer to include a sample from Ryan Bates where `:conditions` option is used in `default_scope`.

Comment: This looks like the closest solution.  Is there any way to declare a named scope to use when loading a model in the controller?

Comment: What should the named scope return?